# Visual Studio Drag and Drop Arrangement of Web Controls

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Just curious,

I remember way back in the ASP.Net 1.0 Visual Studio 2002? days you could just drag a web control onto your visual web form interface to where you wanted it and it would fill in all the CSS styling to make sure that control was in the right spot when viewing the app in a browser.

Did that go away?  I haven't used it in years as I have been hand coding stuff, but for some quick and dirty prototyping I thought it might be useful. Is that capability gone, or do I need to enable that somewhere?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET 1.0 - 1.1  the style attribute was automatically added but in ASP.NET 2.0 onwards this is not a default behavior.

However here is a workaround

1. To set the style properties for each control you add
2. [VS2010]You can set Tools->Options->HTML Designer->CSS Styling

Check -> Change positioning to absolute for controls added using Toolbox, paste or drag and drop
Choose -> Auto Style Application

Answer (score 0):

That was a horrible, disgusting feature that they got rid of for excellent reason. It used absolute positioning to place the control at the particular point on the page, as though the page were a VB6 form. It produced horrible, unmaintainable results.

Comment: It seems to be that NOW would actually be the time to retool and add this feature back.  Maybe push it to a webmatrix like tool but make it commercial for 199 or something...it would fill a need.

Comment: Visual Basic should was a big hit. Originally that was the idea behind web forms. Web wasn't there yet. Maybe with broader support of basic CSS / HTML features, time would be now.  I know this will freak out the "craftsmen" of the web, but still would fill a need for small business for quick and dirty internal apps.

Comment: No, what's needed is a tool that allows small businesses to create reasonably-attractive web pages, not  one that makes it easy for them to create unmaintainable and unattractive messes.

Comment: This maintainable meme...I don't see it in reality. I give you you are most likely a more talented web developer and have more experience than I do, perhaps by lots and lots, but I've never seen software scale.  Next team always rebuilds, takes some pieces parts, but the idea of build once tweak indefinitely, thus we must build everything to be highly salable and maintainable, I just haven't seen it.  But my perspective is limited to a just a few fortune 500 companies, I haven't worked for a lot of them.  And who says the drag and drop components can't be attractive? See Telerik...